# Statistics of cumulative sum of Poisson process

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to understand a link here between the Poisson and Exponential distributions. Here I have drawn values from a Poisson process and computed the cumulative sum

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Intensity of process
lam = 16
bins = 100
length_vec = 10000
poisson = np.random.poisson(lam,length_vec)
z_poisson = np.cumsum(poisson)
print('mean difference poisson cumsum = ',np.mean(np.diff(z_poisson)))
print('mean difference between poisson vals =',np.mean(np.abs(np.diff(poisson))))

#Histogram Poisson Process Vector
plt.hist(poisson, bins=bins)
plt.title('Poisson Process')
plt.xlabel('z')
plt.ylabel('count')

plt.show()
plt.close()

#Histogram Poisson Process Cumulative Sum Difference
plt.hist(np.diff(z_poisson), bins=bins)
plt.title('Poisson Process Interval Difference')
plt.xlabel('z')
plt.ylabel('count')

plt.show()
```

The first plot is a histogram of the Poisson process

[image]

and the second plot is a histogram of the difference of the elements of the cumulative sum of the Poisson process

[image]

If I take the mean of the difference between the cumulative sum elements vector, that value is

```
print('mean difference poisson cumsum = ',np.mean(np.diff(z_poisson)))
mean difference poisson cumsum = 16.000300030003
```

which is approximately almost equal to the intensity of the Poisson process. Does this mean that...

A) The increments of my cumulative sum z_{j+1}-z_j are Poisson distributed

B) The intensity of the process governs the size of the increments? I thought that the increments would be of size 1/lam ?

Lookinh for some general advice...can delete if not the correct stack. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cross posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864291/statistics-of-cumulative-sum-of-poisson-process

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate "the difference of the elements of the cumulative sum" of any series, you recover the original series.* This is true by the definition of *cumulative sum*, you are simply reversing that operation.

So your two plots are expected to be exactly* the same, because the two series are the same. In particular, they have the same mean (give or take a bit of numerical error).

This is true for any series, so it doesn't tell us anything about the Poisson distribution itself.

---

(*) As @Henry points out, you may lose the original first value though.

Comment: You may also lose the first value if you calculate "the difference of the elements of the cumulative sum"

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing that out. I've added it to the answer.